# Filling Dates with Values in Between - MySQL

Tags: mysql, case

I have a table that contains three fields. I am using mysql workbench 6.3 and I just have read access  to the database.

```
ID    REVENUE    DATEFIELD
-1    100        2018-01-05
 1    200        2018-02-03
 3      0        NULL
 6    700        2018-03-05
 9    400        2018-06-30
10      0        NULL
11      0        NULL
12      0        NULL
```

The date field contains a NULL value when the revenue is 0.
I am trying to populate the NULL values in this DATEFIELD with a value between the two rows.

For example:

```
ID REVENUE         DATEFIELD
-1     100        2018-01-05
 1     200        2018-02-03
 3       0        2018-02-05
 6     700        2018-03-05
 9     400        2018-06-30
10       0        2018-06-30
11       0        2018-06-30
12       0        2018-06-30
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use a user-defined variable `@current_date` that you set to the date from each row, and increment when the date is `NULL`.

Comment: Why is the last date in the result `2018-06-30` instead of `2018-07-01`?

Comment: Why is row 3 `2018-02-05` instead of `2018-02-04`? Can it be *any* date between `2018-02-03` and `2018-03-05`?

Comment: @Barmar made pretty good comment's please answer them.. Also provide your MySQL you can know it with `SELECT VERSION()`.. This question seams it be most easy solvable in MySQL 8.0+ because of `LAG()` and `LEAD()` function support.. Also i see a problem with the order because you didn't provide a column where we can indentify the order by like a column with AUTO_INCREMENT or a datetime/timestamp column with on update current timestamp.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Looks like it's ordered by the `ID` column.

Comment: Might be @Barmar but that data looks like a "manual" inserted data which does not seam to follow a "native fixed sequence" (if you know what i mean) the `-1` looks a bit suspect..

Comment: You still haven't explained the logic. Where are the replacement dates coming from? Why are the last 3 dates the same?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, as mentioned in the comments

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  REVENUE, 
  CASE WHEN DATEFIELD IS NULL 
    THEN @d := @d + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
    ELSE @d := DATEFIELD 
  END as DATEFIELD
FROM yourtable t, (SELECT @d := CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 999 DAY) r
ORDER BY ID
```

@d is initialized to 999 days ago. If datefield column is null we take the last value of @d and add a day to it (and return it) otherwise we take the row value of datevalue and store it in@d (and return it)

Comment: You should use `ORDER BY ID`, otherwise the order is unpredictable.

Comment: I tried using the datefield as a variable: 
(SELECT @d := datefield) r
but when I do that I get an error:
Unknown column 'datefield' in 'field list' 0.047 sec

Comment: @MelanieWill The subquery is just to give a default initial value to the variable, it doesn't select from any tables, so it can't refer to a column name. You assign to it from the table in the main query.

Comment: I'll always be puzzled why, after handing someone some working code, they change it so it stops working then they come back going "er, I changed this, and now it doesn't work."